# How to use jquery.hover() using jquery.bind()?

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a table and replacing it in to a div in an aspx page. In that table I have four columns and in each columns i have a particular class. The content of div (ie table) will be changed using `$ajax()` everytime when a dropdownlist changes it value.I am getting the table and it will be coming inside the div.What i requires is I need to do `jquery.hover()` in that particular class.So how can i do by giving the class name. I have already tested `$.('.ovr')bind(mouseover,mouseout)`.But this is also not works. Can u pls give a solution?

Comment: Does `$('.ovr').hover(mouseover, mouseout)` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to bind a "hover" event manually you have to bind the mouseenter and mouseleave events (jQuery's [hover documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) mentions that hover actually binds mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers). Something like this should work:

```
$("...").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        // hover in
    } else {
        // hover out
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#id_of_your_table')
    .delegate('.ovr','mouseover',function(){
      your_mouseover_behavior();
    })
    .delegate('.ovr','mouseout',function(){
      your_mouseout_behavior();
    });

});
```